# How to confirm Centos 7 mirror

Tags: centos7, yum, mirror, confirmation

I recently decided to disable `fastestmirror` plugin on my Centos 7 and added a specific mirror, which I want to use, because it is much faster. The `fastestmirror` plugin is not picking the fastest mirror for me.

I added my preferred mirror `baseurl=http://specific.mirror.com` in `/etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Base.repo` for the Base, Updates and Extras.

Then tried to update my system (clean all and then update). All went well, however, there was no information output at all that my specific mirror is being used for the updates.

I tried to use tcpdump while updating and installing other packages, however, I do not see my specific mirror in the output at all.

My question is: How can I confirm that yum is actually pulling the updates and other packages from my specific mirror? I mean, I want to see the url of my specific mirror being poked by yum. Can this be done?

Comment: Yes, and I also removed the cache files (as yum suggested).

Comment: double check the config file has `enabled=1` set as well. Can you post the output from a yum attempt

Comment: I seem to have it working now. What I did was, I enabled fastestmirror plugin again and removed my specified mirror urls, then rebooted my server and again disabled fastestmirror plugin and set my specific mirror urls. And it just works now and I see the connections in tcpdump. Possibly a reboot was required (or could be some cache problem / bug - it's always the cache's fault ha ha). Anyway, I am grateful for your effort `user3788685`. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, the problem was resolved by:

1. Re-enabling fastestmirror plugin and removing the specified
   mirror urls from the Centos Base repo.
2. Server reboot.
3. Disabling fastestmirror plugin and setting the specific mirror urls in the Centos Base repo once again.